# I have a TextView that always shows up with a fixed size

Tags: android, xml, view, textview, width

I am fixing the UI details of a chat bot and a textview is stuck in a fixed size, I cannot figure out why this happens. It was working as expected but after some changes mostly in values files it has the result that you can see in the link below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="end"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="@dimen/size_8dp">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    tools:text="User" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/chat_bubble_max_width"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/user_bubble_bck"
    android:hint="@string/user_text_hint"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/chat_bubble_horizontal_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/chat_bubble_vertical_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/chat_bubble_horizontal_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/chat_bubble_vertical_padding"
    android:textColor="@color/user_bubble_text"
    android:textColorHint="@color/user_bubble_text"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
    android:textFontWeight="400"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X25TB.jpg)

Comment: Found out the problem, but i dont know why it was affecting the TextView size. The fixed size was the hint's size. When i remove the hint it works as expected. 
If anyone has some insight why it is happening, be free to post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess it happens because of maxWidth parameter. Remove that parameter if you don't really need it and set layout_width to match_parent.

Comment: it does not changes anything. Btw this parameter is set by the designer.

Comment: can you share what is inside drawable file "user_bubble_bck"

Answer (score -1):

Remove `android:hint`  Otherwise, your textview size will be  either the `android:hint` value or the `android:text` value whichever is bigger\longer in characters.

Comment: these are the dimens 
<!--chat bubble-->
  <dimen name="chat_bubble_max_width">260dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="chat_bubble_horizontal_padding">10dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="chat_bubble_vertical_padding">4dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="chat_bubble_top_margin">4dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="chat_bubble_corner_radius">2dp</dimen>